# Read all Digital input in arduino once time and sent theme to serial

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

i need to read all Read all Digital input in arduino once time; example:

```
Serial.write(digitalRead(0),digitalRead(1),...,digitalRead(13));
```

to receive state of all digital pin in one times from my app build with delphi

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Serial.write(digitalRead(0),digitalRead(1),...,digitalRead(13)); not working , i need to get function like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("<");
  for (int p = 0; p < 14; p++)
  {
    Serial.print(digitalRead(p));
  }
  Serial.println(">");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the pin mapping](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168), D0-D13 and A0-A5 are mapped to ports B, C, and D. So simply read the raw ports as bytes, send the values, and decode them on the other side.

```
Serial.write(PINB);
Serial.write(PINC);
Serial.write(PIND);
```

Note that A6 and A7 (on boards that have them) are not mapped to digital pins and so cannot be read in this way.

Comment: iam tring this command but not working for me , any one can help me with example or demo ?